# REcover or reconstruct the CQL string from a geotools Filter object

Tags: java, geotools

I want to know if there is a way to get the CQL string that was used to create a Filter object can be recovered or reconstructed, such that it could be used to create the same filter again. 
i.e.

```
Filter filter = ECQL.toFilter("name = 'bob'");
String ecqlString = /* Some code that gets the "name = 'bob'" string back with quotations preserved*/
Filter filter2 = ECQL.toFilter(ecqlString);
```

The toString() method removes all quoations and I cant find a way to identify weather expressions were originally Strings or numbers useing a visitor. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for the function ECQL.toCQL(Filter).

Note that there can be a few string representations of a GeoTools Filter object.

Comment: Thanks! I dont know how I didnt see this before!